# How to Serialize in EF5 with ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

I'm using .Net 4.5 and Entity Framework 5.0.
I have 3 basic entity classes created using the Code-First approach. Now I'm trying to serialize it and am unable.

Here's the basics of the classes:

***Base class***

```
public class BaseEntity
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

***Derived Classes***

```
public class ChildEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public ParentEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public class ParentEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual ICollection<ChildEntity> Rules { get; set; }

    public RuleGroup()
    {
      this.Rules = new HashSet<ChildEntity>();
    }
}
```

***My Context Class***

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ParentEntity> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChildEntity> Childs { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext()
        : base("MyDbContext")
    {
    }
}
```

I've tryed to serialize with:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(destinationFile))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Parents>));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, context.Parents.ToList());
    }
}
```

But it looks like I can't serialize `ICollection<T>`.

Changed it to `List<T>` but still gives me problems.

How can I serialize\deserialize to\from XML this simple structure of classes ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to iterate the collection yourself. You'll find this still causes you problems if you are using EF Proxy classes for change tracking/lazy loading (which it looks to me like you are as you have `virtual ICollection`'s).

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(destinationFile))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parent));
        writer.WriteStartElement("ArrayOfParent");
        foreach(Parent parent in BdContext.Parents)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, parent);
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

you can turn Proxies off with [this setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.proxycreationenabled%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) and doing so should also fix your original code.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext ()
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Tryed it and it didn't work giving out the following exception:  `Message "The type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Parent_E76FB33E6995E673A0E176C3BF1491089D201114AF560D2CB455BDBBD74C633A was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."`

Comment: @Gil that message is the confirmation that you have EF Proxy classes. You'll probably have to create separate DTO classes that can be serialized and use something like AutoMapper to copy the data to/from one and the other.

Comment: If I add `[XmlIgnore]` on top of `public virtual ICollection<ChildEntity> Rules { get; set; }` in the ParentEntity I can Serialize it but it seams that the problem is within the `ICollection<T>`. Is there a wrapper or a way to serialize the content without creating DTO's ?